# Downloaded image has bigger size than wanted

Tags: ios, json, xcode, image, uiimageview

**PROBLEM**

I'm working on an app where I download data from a JSON file that's uploaded on a website. Everything downloaded shows up correctly... but I have this UIImageView of size 54x54 that whenever I try to download the image from the JSON file it presents itself with its original size and not the Image View's size.

This is a problem when it comes to retina devices because the image has to be the same size as the image view.

How can I make the image resize at the right measurements?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOQz5.png

This what I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [arrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(70, 8, 209, 21);

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [arraySubtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(70, 29, 209, 33);
    label.numberOfLines = 2;

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 54, 54);

    cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I created a UITableViewCell class and implemented all the attributes of my labels and image view:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 54, 54);
    title.frame = CGRectMake(79, 14, 200, 21);
    subtitle.frame = CGRectMake(79, 31, 200, 33);
    date.frame = CGRectMake((self.window.frame.size.width - 140), 0, 100, 21);
}
```

And then I called it in my TableViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.title.text = [arrayTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.subtitle.text = [arraySubtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.date.text = [arrayDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use this or try reducing size for frame.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
or

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: This didn't help but I already edited my answer that includes the solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Image size is perfect but what you are missing is the few properties- (any one options from below two options can solve your problem.)

1. Content mode: Right now, which is **AspectFill**. It should be
   either **ScaleToFill** or **AspectFit** as per your requirements.

   `[imageView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];`
   or
   `[imageView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];`
2. Don't forget to turn on **ClipSubviews** of the `UIImageView`.

   `[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];`